# Find $Aut(\mathbb{C}*)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $Aut(\mathbb{C}*)$ , the group of automorphisms of field of complex numbers without zero.

I try studing the Laurent series, I know $a z$ and $\frac{a}{z}$ are in $Aut(\mathbb{C}*)$.
But I dont know how to continue.

Comment: Please define "automorphism".

Comment: Yes, automorphism = biholomorphic map, sorry, english is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

Any  $f\in Aut(\mathbb C^*)$ will either have pole at $0$ or at $\infty.$
If it has pole only at $\infty$ then it has to be a simple pole as near $\infty$ $f$ behaves like $n$ to $1$ function. Now, $f$ being entire then $f$ has to be a linear polynomial, again $f$ takes the value $0$ at $0.$ So, $f$ takes the form $f(z)=az(a\ne 0).$

Again, if $f$ has pole at 0, then similarly it's a simple pole.
Now, $\frac{1}{f}\in Aut(\mathbb C^*)$ such that, it has pole only at $\infty.$Therefore, $\frac{1}{f(z)}=az$ i.e. $f(z)=\frac{1}{az}(a\ne 0)$